# Php order multidimensional array by first key external value

Tags: php, arrays

I need to reorder multidimensional array by Region Name.
But my multiarray is actually indexed by REGION_ID (first key) for semplicity like:

```
$array = array(
  1 => array(   // 1 is REGION_ID
    "Value" => "Val-1",
    "Children" => array(
       ...
    )
  ),
  2 => array(   // 2 is REGION_ID
    "Value" => "Val-2",
    "Children" => array(
       ...
    )
  ),
  3 => array(   // 3 is REGION_ID
    "Value" => "Val-3",
    "Children" => array(
       ...
    )
  ), 
  4 => array(   // 4 is REGION_ID
    "Value" => "Val-4",
    "Children" => array(
       ...
    )
  ),
  ...
);

foreach ( $array as $region_id => $sub_array ) {
  var_dump($region_id);
}
```

Where my table REGION is:

```
ID   |   Name
--------------
1    |  Emilia
--------------
2    |  Calabria
--------------
3    |  Veneto
--------------
4    |  Puglia
--------------
...
```

I'd like, so, to reorder my $array by Name of my table:
Calabria, then, Emilia, Puglia, Veneto... so my $array has to be:

```
$array = array(
      2 => array(   
        "Value" => "Val-2",
        "Children" => array(
           ...
        )
      ),
      1 => array(  
        "Value" => "Val-1",
        "Children" => array(
           ...
        )
      ),
      4 => array(   
        "Value" => "Val-4",
        "Children" => array(
           ...
        )
      ), 
      3 => array( 
        "Value" => "Val-3",
        "Children" => array(
           ...
        )
      ),
      ...
    );
```

I don't know how to sort using my logic...

Comment: you should used `order by name ASC` in mysql query rather than in array

Comment: Do you retrieve the data from a db? If yes in your query order by `Name ASC`

Comment: use `region_name` instead of `region_id`

Comment: alternatively, if you need to resort the array later, you can use the usort methods php implements, those aloow to specify a user implemented compaarison function to tell the order of two array elements by any comparison you want to implement.

Comment: I get values from DB but, for technical rules, i can't order by Name.. I need to reorder $array after i got the result.

Answer (score 1):

assign the correct sorted array from database to $sorting

$sorting = ...[some function to retrive a sorted array from the database in the desired order]

for example "SELECT * FROM `REGION` ORDER BY `Name`"

ERRATA:
if you can't add the "ORDER BY" to sql query, just get the values and use usort (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to have the $sorting array in the correct order.

so, you should have something like (eqivalent):

```
$sorting = [
    ['ID' => 2, 'Name' => 'Calabria'],
    ['ID' => 1, 'Name' => 'Emilia'],
    ['ID' => 4, 'Name' => 'Puglia'],
    ['ID' => 3, 'Name' => 'Veneto']
];
```

or var_dump($sorting)

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'ID' => int 2
      'Name' => string 'Calabria' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'ID' => int 1
      'Name' => string 'Emilia' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'ID' => int 4
      'Name' => string 'Puglia' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'ID' => int 3
      'Name' => string 'Veneto' (length=6)
```

now run the following loop:

```
$sorted_array = [];
foreach ($sorting as $sort_element) {
    $sorted_array[] = $array[$sort_element['ID']];
}
```

the $sorted_array will have the required sort order

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Value' => string 'Val-2' (length=5)
      'Children' => ...
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Value' => string 'Val-1' (length=5)
      'Children' => ...
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Value' => string 'Val-4' (length=5)
      'Children' => ...
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Value' => string 'Val-3' (length=5)
      'Children' => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
  1 => array(   
      "Value" => "Val-1",
      "Children" => array(
     )
  ),
  2 => array(  
    "Value" => "Val-2",
    "Children" => array(
    )
  ),
  3 => array(   
    "Value" => "Val-3",
    "Children" => array(
    )
  ), 
  4 => array( 
    "Value" => "Val-4",
    "Children" => array(
    )
  ),
);

$region = array(1 => 'Emilia', 2 => 'Calabria', 3 => 'Veneto', 4 => 'Puglia');
asort($region);
$new_array = [];

foreach ($region as $key => $value) {
  $new_array[ $key ] = $array[ $key ];
}

print_r($new_array);
```

You can see this working here : http://tpcg.io/K23FfH